# Using Virtualbox, with Ubuntu as host, do I have to re-install Windows as the guest?

Tags: virtualbox

I am running dual boot, so I have both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make clear exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please describe more your situation, your question is not so clear... thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you already have Windows installed on your hard disk, usually there is no need to install it in VirtualBox. The only advantage to additionally create a Windows VM in VirtualBox is to launch Windows from within the running Ubuntu system ... but does this really make any sense at all ... ?
In case you you decide to only use Ubuntu and wipe Windows from the hard disk - it would make more sense to create a Windows VM in VirtualBox for occasionally using Windows as a guest OS.